# select statement giving error for string variable

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am writing the following SQL query in my Java program

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from "                 
    + "student where ID =" + ID + " or FirstName=" + firstName + ";");
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> use the right syntax for FirstName="+Parker

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please give the *exact* error, as well as telling us what the database is, and whether you're getting the error at compile-time or execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of prepared statements by making use of **prepared statements parameters.** This way, you can set your parameters pragmatically using setters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Here is a snippet from the Oracle docs:

```
PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
```

> String updateString = "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " + "set SALES =
>   **?** where COF_NAME = **?**";

```
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);

updateSales.**setInt**(1, e.getValue().intValue());

updateSales.**setString**(2, e.getKey());
```

Just make sure you set the statements **in order a**s the sql query.

Comment: Let me ask, the way my prepared statement is written right now, is there any syntax error in that statement? When I debug my program, the variable firstName contains a value(which is Parker) but I wonder why it tells me that there is syntax error. Its hard to get the actual error because I can see it when I hover over my PrintStackTrace object.But it basically says " check the manual that corresponds with it, sql error near FirstName="+Parker

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PreparedStatement` like this:

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from student where ID = ? or FirstName = ?");
pre.setInt(1, ID);
pre.setString(2, firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used sql in Java, but my guess is it is because you don't have single quotes around first name. You want:

```
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select ID,FirstName,LastName,Dept from " + "student where ID =" + ID + " or FirstName='" + firstName + "';");
```

emphasis:

```
... FirstName='" + firstName + "';");
```